# Google Cloud Storage OATH mod_proxy

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Folks,
  What is the proper way to configure Apache to pass OATH authentication information?  We are trying to front a storage bucket with apache, and have the following configuration:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
ProxyPass /bucketname https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname
RequestHeader add Authorization "Bearer 4/_gCUxIJoLgasdl;fkjasdfldjsfjksdfYGjYfAI"
```

I am very new to OATH.  From what I have gathered, you can specify the authentication parameters via HTTP headers, and pass them along to GCS.  With the config above, I get the following:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code>
<Message>Authentication required.</Message>
</Error>
```

What other information do i need to specify with mod_headers?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Are you trying to get Apache to proxy requests which already have a correct Authorization header? Or have Apache handle authorization and proxy a whole bucket to unauthenticated users?

Comment: @BrianDorsey Apache proxies the bucket to 'unauthorized users'  THANKS!

Comment: The bucket must remain restricted to any other requests except for the specific apache instances

Comment: Where did you get the Bearer string from? The Bearer string is an access token, which expires. You'd have to regenerate the access token from a refresh token periodically. I don't think you could do that without a server-side script.

Comment: Could I ask more about the use case? What is your end goal? What is the context? (Where will this be running? Can the HTTP clients use Oauth2 themselves?)